# What is the interpretation of $\delta(x)\ln\delta(x)$, where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac's delta function?

Tags: distribution-theory

What's the result of the following integral?

$$\int f(x)\delta(x)\ln\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

where $f(x)$ is a smooth function (continuous derivatives of as high order as needed).

Comment: I'm not aware of any definition that would give this integral a value. What definition do you have in mind?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I'm not aware of all the possible definitions of the Dirac delta function, and I don't have that much practice with it. I've only used it in easy-to-interpret physical problems. I suppose one could try using one of the limits given here: http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/. I suppose that the limit should be taken outside the integral, but I am not sure.

Comment: (What have you tried?) Try to use two different limit representations of Dirac-delta and change the order of integral and limit. What will you obtain? Which of them has physical meaning? Maybe, it could help us if you sketch your physical problems.

Comment: OK, I'll explicitly conjecture what @vesszabo seems to have implied, namely that if you represent $\delta(x)$ as one of the limits at the wolfram site, say $\lim f_n(x)$, and then form the functions $f_n(x)\ln f_n(x)$, the results either will converge to something that depends on the particular $f_n$ sequence that you chose or (more likely) will not converge at all in the sense of distributions. In less precise but perhaps more useful terms, I conjecture that there is no such distribution as $\delta(x)\ln\delta(x)$.

Comment: We can imagine many 'bizarre' expressions which involve the Dirac delta functions.

Comment: @vesszabo The physical interpretation arises from the computation of an entropy term. In my actual problem $x$ is a vector and the integral is multi-dimensional. I thought that I could simplify the issue by going to one-dimension. But I don't think that's a good idea anymore. By the comments and answer here, it seems that in one-dimension the integral has no sensible definition. Maybe with more dimensions the problem is more interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approximation to $\delta$ (located at $0$ on the real line) is the sequence $$\phi_n(x) = \begin{cases} n/2 ,\quad & |x|\le 1/n \\ 0 \quad & |x|>1/n\end{cases}$$ 
It is reasonable to interpret $\phi_n \ln \phi_n $ as $0$ when $\phi_n=0$, since linear decay beat logarithm. Hence,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f (x) \phi_n(x)\ln \phi_n(x)\,dx = \frac{n}{2} \ln\frac{n}{2} \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} f(x)\,dx
$$
Since $f(x)-f(0)=O(x)$, it follows that
$$
\frac{n}{2}\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} f(x)\,dx = f(0)  +  \frac{n}{2}\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} (f(x)-f(0))\,dx = f(0)+O(1/n)
$$
Thus, 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f (x) \phi_n(x)\ln \phi_n(x)\,dx = f(0)  \ln\frac{n}{2}  + O\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)$$

As $n\to \infty$, the limit is infinite if $f(0)\ne 0$, and zero otherwise. This is not a continuous functional on the space of smooth functions; in other words, not  a distribution.