# What is logarithm of Dirac Delta function?

Tags: dirac-delta

My conjecture is $\ln(\delta(x))=-\ln(x)\delta(x)-\gamma$, but I am not sure.

Comment: can have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/625966/399263, by itself probably undefined since -infinite value almost everywhere, and from this post $\delta\ln(\delta)$ is slightly better but not much.

Comment: How do you define $\ln \delta$?

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function.  So what is your definition of $\log(\delta(x))$?

Comment: You could use [this Wolfram functions point](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/03/02/) to get $\ln(\delta(x))=-\infty,x\ne0$ and $\ln(\delta(0))=\infty$, but there are multiple definitions of $\delta(x)$

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be defined as a distribution. If you consider the logarithmic function $\ln$ as a distribution, the quantity: $\ln \circ g$  can be defined as a distribution only if $g$ is invertible and both $g$ and its inverse are smooth functions. This is not the case for $g=\delta$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995920/how-is-the-dirac-delta-delta-x3-different-from-deltax/3996594#3996594) for why we need $g$ to be smooth. The difficulty stems from the fact that the composition operator is a nonlinear operator and nonlinear operations are hard to handle in the standard theory of distributions.